# How to multiple decimal numbers in column within a group by?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have sql table that looks like this:

```
date                  id       value     type
2020-01-01            1        1.03      a
2020-01-01            1        1.02      a
2020-01-02            2        1.06      a
2020-01-02            2        1.2       a
2020-01-03            3        1.09      b
```

I need to build a query that groups by date,id, and type  by multiplying the value column whereever type = 'a'.

what new table should look like:

```
date                  id       value      type
2020-01-01            1        1.0506      a
2020-01-02            2        1.272       a
2020-01-03            3        1.09        b
```

currently I am building this query,

```
select 
date, id, value, type
from my_table
where date between 'some date' and 'some date'

and trying to fit in EXP(SUM(LOG(value)
```

but, how do I do the multiplication only where type = 'a' in a group by?

edit:

1. there are more than 2 values in the `type` column
2. I am using redshift. Not postgresql.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that was something that came up in the below response. I will update the question to reflect the change.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I confirmed I am using redshif.t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date
     , id
     -- use the 'case' syntax to check if it is type 'a'
     , case when type = 'a' then EXP(SUM(LOG(value::float))) -- your multiply logic
            else max(value) -- use min or max to pick only one value
       end as value
  from my_table
 where date between 'some date' and 'some date'
 group
    by date, id, type
```

Comment: I have more than 2 values in the type column, how would I alter you query to take into consideration that there are more than 2 values in the type column? 

I have tried `type !='a'` but i get error `specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables`

Comment: I have inverted the logic. Now it will multiply when type = 'a', else pick the max value only.

Comment: you can add more cases like `when type = 'c' then 'do your magic'`

Comment: use type <> “a” , not type != “a”

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CASE_function.html

Comment: remove the multiply logic and use sum(value), just to check

Comment: the sum works after removing the mulitplication.

Comment: So, the code works... your solution to multiply is not working ... some of the functions does not exist.

Comment: yup, must not be available in redshift how I am trying to multiple.

Comment: Probably. You must use a different logic to multiply.

Comment: if you add `::float` to `value` like so `value::float` in the multiplication it works. I can accept that answer.